# Which Raspberry Pi 3B+ GPIO pin is connected to which module in Adeept Motor Hat v2.0?

Tags: raspberry-pi, python, gpio-external-interrupt

I need to find out which GPIO pin on the raspberry pi will be connected to which module when I fit the Adeept Motor Hat v2.0 on the 40 GPIO pins. I am attaching the image and the schematic of the motor hat.

[image: Motor hat which fits on the 40 GPIO pins of Raspberry pi]

[Here](https://docdro.id/tyeUsts) is a link to the schematic.

[Alternate link to the schematic](https://pdfhost.io/v/z0UjR2mj_CircuitSchematicAdeeptMotorShieldV20pdf.pdf)

PS. Since I am new to this I am not sure if this can be figured out or not.
Thanks!

Comment: Which Raspberry Pi? Also your link doens't work.

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3B+, sir.

Comment: https://pdfhost.io/v/z0UjR2mj_CircuitSchematicAdeeptMotorShieldV20pdf.pdf
Link to the schematic. Please see if this works?

Comment: PCA9685 as motor driver HAT: with the correct speaker (read: motor) this PWM control adjustable from about 24 Hz to 1526 Hz makes this HAT a nice sound card!

Comment: @Huisman Sir, I did not understand.

Comment: You will hear the motor making sound because the PWM modulating range lies within the hearing range. They should have used the PCA96**3**5 instead, which is around 97.6 kHz (The PCA9635 however has lower PWM resolution)

Comment: So, you have the schematic at hand. Why can't you find out the connections of interest by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already found the schematic for the Motor Hat.

[image]

Now we need the schematic of the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi. That's why I asked which one you use. Since AFAIK they are not all equal. [RPi 3B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/) [schematic GPIO](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3bplus_1p0_reduced.pdf):

[image]

Now we check the 40 pins, and see if they are equal. And they are! Even the warning in the picture of the RPi is correct in the schematic of the Motor Hat.

So we can conclude that the module will fit.

Additional comment from OP:

> can you help me with respect to the modules and the pins ie (ultrasonic sensor, line tracking sensor, motor1, motor2, RGB led1, RGB led2). I wanted to know that which module will connect to which GPIO pins so that I can program in python using those GPIO pins ie. when I connect the sensors to the HAT, which pins should I use while programming ?

You do this by checking the datasheet your link. So for example in the case of tracking, ultrasonic sensor and the WS2812

[image]

- tracking: connects to GPIO19, GPIO16, GPIO20
- ultrasonic: connects to GPIO11, GPIO08
- WS2812: connects to GPIO12

Comment: Sir, can you help me with respect to the modules and the pins ie (ultrasonic sensor, line tracking sensor, motor1, motor2, RGB led1, RGB led2). I wanted to know that which module will connect to which GPIO pins so that I can program in python using those GPIO pins ie. when I connect the sensors to the HAT, which pins should I use while programming ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Vaibhav updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, Sir!  Sir, what about Motor 1 and Motor 2? 
Also, Sir what are the parallel rows of black, red, and yellow pins on the hat(refer to the diagram)

Comment: @Vaibhav check the datasheet. I'm not going to copy pasta another picture here. You can see that motorA and motorB are connected to an L298. Looking at the schematic you can see that pin 7, 8, 9 and pin 13, 14, 15 are connected to the RPi with their respective GPIO pins.

Comment: @Vaibhav Also I dont understand what you mean by the diagram

Comment: I mean the diagram of the motor driver provide in the question.